# Understanding tightness of a set of measures (any subset of a tight set is tight)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

This is the definition I have of tightness of a set of measures on a metric space:

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. A family of probability measures $\Pi$ defined on the Borel sets of $X$ is said to be tight if for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a compact set $K_{\epsilon} \subset X$ such that for all $\mu \in \Pi$, $\mu(K_{\epsilon}) > 1 - \epsilon$.

Does this imply that any subset of a tight space is tight? Surely we can just use the same sets $K_{\epsilon}$ to verify the tightness condition. This feels to good to be true though.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Does this then imply (by Prokhorov's theorem) that every subset of a compact set of measures is itself compact?

Comment: No. Remember: Prokhorov states that tight sets have a compact closure.

Comment: Thanks. I was getting confused over the difference between "relatively compact" and compact